# How can I make this python code shorter and more efficient

Tags: python

This is my attempt at doing a higher/lower game.

```
import random
print("A game of Higher or Lower")
number = random.randint(1, 100)
choice = int(input("Please pick a number between 1 & 100: "))
if choice < number:
    print("Higher")
elif choice > number:
    print("Lower")
else:
    print("Well done!")
while choice != number:
    choice = int(input("Pick again: "))
    if choice < number:
        print("Higher")
    elif choice > number:
        print("Lower")
    else:
        print("Well done!")
```

I'm new to python and I'm just wondering is there a way of shortening the code to make it more efficient? Don't think there is a need for two 'if/elif/else' statements but can't see a way to merge them. Sorry if it's a stupid question!

Updated Code:

```
import random
print("A game of Higher or Lower")
number = random.randint(1, 100)
choice = ""
while choice != number:
    choice = int(input("Please pick a number: "))
    if choice < number:
        print("Higher")
    elif choice > number:
        print("Lower")
    else:
        print("Well done!")
```

Comment: Every time you catch yourself duplicating code, ask yourself "can i put this in a function?"

Comment: Found it. I let 'choice' be a empty string so it's defined when it comes to the while loop

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about improving working code are off-topic on Stack Overflow. Consider taking the tour at CodeReview.StackExchange and see if your question fits there, instead.

Comment: Also, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question isn't a stupid one, but do be sure to check out our [tour] to get a good idea of the structure of the site!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
import random
print("A game of Higher or Lower")
number = random.randint(1, 100)
while True:
    try:
        choice = int(input("Please pick a number between 1 & 100: "))
    except ValueError:
        continue
    if choice < number:
        print("Higher")
    elif choice > number:
        print("Lower")
    else:
        print("Well done!")
        break
```

Comment: If the user don't input anything, this will raise a `ValueError`. But anyways it answers the question.

Comment: @Manjunath I added a try/except to fix that scenario

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion: initialize `choice` with something that is guaranteed to be unequal `number` (e.g. a negative number, a "sentinel"). Then you can start with the while loop right away, because the condition will always be true for the first time.

Then you can remove the first if/then/else block and the first call to `input()` outside the while loop.

BTW, "shorter code" is not always "efficient code" :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
import random
print("A game of Higher or Lower")

number = random.randint(1, 100)
choice = int(input("Please pick a number between 1 & 100: "))

while choice != number:
    if choice < number:
        print("Higher")
    elif choice > number:
        print("Lower")

    choice = int(input("Pick again: "))

print("Well done")
```

Encapsulating the code that check user input may also be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

the if/else statements can be put on one line:

```
import random
print("A game of Higher or Lower")
number = random.randint(1, 100)
choice = ""
while choice != number:
    choice = int(input("Please pick a number: "))
    s = 'Higher' if choice < number else ('Lower' if choice > number else 'Well done!')
    print(s)
```

If you want to minimize the number of characters, change the var names to just "initials" like:

```
import random
print("A game of Higher or Lower")
n = random.randint(1, 100)
c = ""
while c != n:
    c = int(input("Please pick a number: "))
    s = 'Higher' if c < n else ('Lower' if c > n else 'Well done!')
    print(s)
```